# Weird <hr> tag behavior

Tags: html, css

When I try to put an hr tag after a div whose text has been wrapped, the div appears like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ah4VG/1/). If you look carefully, the line is on the side, in the middle of the paragraph. It works fine if the text isn't wrapped, but how do I fix this for multiple line posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `hr { clear: both; }` to your style definitions. Otherwise it will be rendered next to the enclosing paragraph that is floating left.

I updated your [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ah4VG/4/) accordingly.

Comment: WOW, so easy! Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: You will have to wait a few more minutes before you can accept the answer.